# Deconstructing a Document and Media download URL

Tags: liferay-7

I want to keep track of all files downloaded from Document and Media, so I wrote a Servlet Filter that gets URLs when a file is downloaded. Depending from where in the UI the file is downloaded, it can look like these:

```
http://s/documents/20143/32701/SomeFile.txt/da99a46a-8231-2a87-ff8d-8d3b2d388c24
http://s/documents/20143/0/invoice_ABC.pdf/c44fd479-331b-f393-7879-973c5cecf086
```

In my audit I would like to write down details about the downloaded file, so I need to extract info from that URL.

What is each part of the URL for?

*Note: I know that relying on these parameters in this order is dangerous, but when doing audit I don't think there is any better option, as the Java code behind download can not be overridden by an OSGi module.*

Answer (score 1):

- `http://s`: Your protocol and server name, obviously.
- `documents`: A keyword, it is always the same.

What follows is a path with up to four parts. Depending on the count of parts, they can have different meanings:

- `http://s/documents/80327`

  - `80327`: The ID of a FileShortcut (`DLFileShortcut.fileShortcutId`)
  - The file entry may be found with: `DLAppServiceUtil.getFileEntry(DLAppServiceUtil.getFileShortcut(80327).getToFileEntryId())`
- `http://s/documents/20143/da99a46a-8231-2a87-ff8d-8d3b2d388c24`

  - `20143`: The ID of the site/group to which the file entry belongs (`DLFileEntry.groupId`)
  - `da99a46a-8231-2a87-ff8d-8d3b2d388c24`: The UUID of the file entry (`DLFileEntry.uuid`)
  - The file entry may be found with: `DLAppServiceUtil.getFileEntryByUuidAndGroupId("da99a46a-8231-2a87-ff8d-8d3b2d388c24", 20143)`
- `http://s/documents/20143/32701/SomeFile.txt`

  - `20143`: The ID of the site/group to which the file entry belongs (`DLFileEntry.groupId`)
  - `32701`: The ID of the folder to which the file entry belongs (`DLFileEntry.folderId`)
  - `SomeFile.txt`: The file's name, with special characters encoded as URL escape sequences (`DLFileEntry.name`)
  - The file entry may be found with: `DLAppServiceUtil.getFileEntry(20143, 32701, HttpUtil.decodeUrl("SomeFile.txt"))`
- `http://s/documents/20143/32701/SomeFile.txt/da99a46a-8231-2a87-ff8d-8d3b2d388c24`

  - `20143`: The ID of the site/group to which the file entry belongs (`DLFileEntry.groupId`)
  - `32701`: The ID of the folder to which the file entry belongs - ignored
  - `SomeFile.txt`: The file's name - ignored
  - `da99a46a-8231-2a87-ff8d-8d3b2d388c24`: The UUID of the file entry. (`DLFileEntry.uuid`)
  - The file entry may be found with: `DLAppServiceUtil.getFileEntryByUuidAndGroupId("da99a46a-8231-2a87-ff8d-8d3b2d388c24", 20143)`

Liferay usually generates URLs of the last format to have a more or less "friendly" URL which is hardened against moving or renaming of files.

A notable absent is the company id, it can be retrieved from `DLFileEntry.companyId` or `Group.companyId`.

*Warning:*  The elements and their order might change in the future. The current implementation can be found in `com.liferay.portal.webserver.WebServerServlet.getFileEntry(String[] pathArray)`.

*This is a community wiki answer, so feel free to edit it to add/fix information.*